# Change interview location of US B2 and F1 visa

Tags: visas, international-travel, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas, us-visa

I am applying for a student visa and a tourist visa for my parents. In DS-160, I selected the location to be New Delhi. However, when I am trying to schedule the interview date and time from [here](https://cgifederal.secure.force.com/?language=English&country=India), it defaults the Post of Interview to Mumbai.

How do I change the interview's location to Delhi? According to my State of Residence, the default post of interview that I'm getting is Mumbai. However, the earliest available interview dates for Mumbai are in mid-August, and I plan to leave India by the first week of August. The same is with my parents. I understand that it's not an issue to have different interview locations mentioned in DS-160 and in the interview appointment application. Also, in a step by step guide to make a profile for a visa appointment given by this [site](https://www.visatraveler.com/blog/schedule-us-visa-appointment/), it says that we can put our desired consulate location for interview as our Country/State of Residency. I got the same advice after searching for a bit on the net too. However, is it right to do so?

Any help or advice ASAP would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!